# Screen reader(NVDA) is not reading pre-selected value and expanded/collapsed state of mat-select

Tags: angular-material, accessibility, nvda

NVDA is not reading collapse/expanded state of mat-select also it is not reading pre-selected value

Comment: could you improve your question a bit with a fiddle demonstrating the behaviour. The standard examples on the angular-material website work so it may be an issue with your implementation. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

use an aria-expanded attribute for reading collapse/expanded state. you can update the value to true when the dropdown panel opens.

```
<mat-select (openedChange)="isExpanded = $event" [attr.aria-expanded]="isExpanded">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the panelOpen property of the select's local variable

```html
<mat-select #myselect [attr.aria-expanded]="myselect.panelOpen">
```